# whatsapp URL Scheme doesn't give control back to app.

Tags: ios, url-scheme, whatsapp

I am trying to share a link via Whatsapp and have read many tutorials as well. I am able to share my link successfully but the problem is that user doesn't come back to my app after sharing on whatsapp.

Here is the code I am using to share:

```
    NSString *referralLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some link here"];
    NSString *textToSend = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",referralLink] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:textToSend];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
```

I know that I have to use URL Scheme to achive this and I have used it too. But I am not sure that I am using it in correct way.

Here is the screenshot of my .info file.

[image]

Behind the black bar, I have entered the bundle identifier. i.e `com.abc.myapp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior in iOS, only if the app developer of the app you are calling allows an option to send the user back to calling app will it work.

WhatsApp does not have such a feature and this is therefore not possible.

Also you should not use the `whatsapp:` url scheme in your apps `info.plist`. Doing this will make any app calling `whatsapp:` to open your app.

Answer (score 0):

you should give your own `url scheme`(a unique identifier), probably your `AppName`. You are not supposed to use **whatsapp**

Comment: I have replaced whatsapp with my app name but still same behaviour.

Comment: @codeBug WhatsApp will never open your app after it has send the message. Since this is not default behavior in iOS. So only if the developers of WhatsApp add this feature and they give you the specification on what to add to their app scheme to reopen your will it be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Now IOS 9 Do support the Apps to come back to the app when they are invoking any third party app being called using OpenURL scheme.

You can make a OS version based support at this moment unless you come to minimal support of IOS 9 for your application.

[image: Check the top left corner that is now taking you back to app which invoked this safari browser.]